# Use chrome.storage in script loaded by webrequest blocking

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

---

Hello, I have a problem with an extension.
I block an script with `webRequest.onBeforeRequest` but when I trying to use `chrome.storage` console return this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined`

My code:

**background.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
 if( details.url == "http://o1.t26.net/js/application.js?2.0.4" )
            return {redirectUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("load.js") };
    },
    {urls: ["http://o1.t26.net/*.js?2.0.4"]}, ["blocking"]);
```

**load.js**

```
chrome.storage.local.get('test', function (h){
console.log(h.test);
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
"content_scripts": [{
"matches": [ "http://www.agust.in/*", "http://agust.in/*" ],
"js": ["test.js"],
"run_at": "document_start",
"all_frames": true
}
],
"description": "TEST",
"icons": {
"16": "icon_one.png",
"48": "icon_two.png",
"128": "icon_three.png"
},
"name": "Test",
"permissions": ["storage", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "http://www.agust.in/*", "http://agust.in/*",  "http://o1.t26.net/*",  "http://t26.net/*"],
"version": "1.4",
"manifest_version": 2,
"web_accessible_resources": [ "load.js"],
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"],
"persistent": true
}
}
```

btw, the script (load.js) load perfect, sorry for my BADDD english.

Comment: `load.js` is most likely executing in a the browser scope instead of the extension's scope, therefore the `chrome.*` library is not being detected. Can you try console logging `chrome`? If you get an error then thats your problem

Comment: Hi Holiday, return this:>

`chrome.alarms is not available: You do not have permission to access this API. Ensure that the required permission or manifest property is included in your manifest.json. `

>

`chrome.audio is not available: You do not have permission to access this API. Ensure that the required permission or manifest property is included in your manifest.json. `

>

`Object {loadTimes: function, csi: function, alarms: undefined, app: Object, audio: undefined…} `

`Object {loadTimes: function, csi: function, app: Object, webstore: Object}`

>

Using `console.log(chrome)`

Comment: Your website is trying to load `application.js` as a regular script in a `<script>` tag. Instead, it gets back the contents of `load.js` to put in that `<script>` tag. Of course it fails -- a regular website has no idea what `chrome.storage` is. Depending on your needs, a better strategy might be to block the request entirely and use `chrome.tabs.executeScript`.

Answer (score 1):

You're redirecting a script loaded in a normal web page to load.js in your extension. Although load.js is from your extenison, it's loaded and executed in the web page's context, which has no access to `chrome.storage` API.

I'd recommend you cancel that request and inject load.js as a content script.